# Count frequency of an element in a Swift array of elements

Tags: swift

I want to count the frequency of false m's in an array of elements:

```
    import UIKit

struct aW: Hashable, Codable {
    var day: Int
    var w: Double
    var m: Bool
}

let array = [
    aW(day: 0, w: 32.62, m: true),
    aW(day: 1, w: 32.40, m: true),
    aW(day: 2, w: 32.16, m: true),
    aW(day: 3, w: 32.01, m: false),
    aW(day: 4, w: 31.81, m: true),
    aW(day: 5, w: 31.61, m: false),
    aW(day: 6, w: 31.41, m: false),
    aW(day: 7, w: 31.20, m: true),
    aW(day: 8, w: 31.01, m: true),
    aW(day: 9, w: 30.83, m: true)]
```

Also I want to select the first element with a false occurence.

I found a lot of examples for frequencies for arrays of strings or int's. But how do you do this with an array of such elements?

Comment: This is not an array of tuples (nor valid JSON). The code doesn't compile.

Comment: Sorry, I'll change my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use reduce. If the element's `m` property is true return the same partial result otherwise return the partial result plus one:

```
let count = array.reduce(0) { $1.m ? $0 : $0 + 1 }
count // 3
```

To get the first element that is false you can use first where predicate:

```
if let element = array.first(where: { !$0.m }) {
    print(element)  // AW(day: 3, w: 32.01, m: false)
}
```

Note that it is Swift naming convention to name your structs starting with an uppercase letter. You should also use better descriptive naming.

Comment: another possibility would be `array.lazy.filter { $0.m }.count`

Comment: I prefer using reduce considering it will iterate the whole collection. Btw I would use key path syntax `array.lazy.filter(\.m).count` if OP would be counting the `true` elements but note that OP wants the false count `{ !$0.m }`.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if you’re interested. Below is the playground `combine` version for **@Leo Dabus** answer.

```
var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()

struct aW: Hashable, Codable {
    var day: Int
    var w: Double
    var m: Bool
}

let array = [
     aW(day: 0, w: 32.62, m: true),
     aW(day: 1, w: 32.40, m: true),
     aW(day: 2, w: 32.16, m: true),
     aW(day: 3, w: 32.01, m: false),
     aW(day: 4, w: 31.81, m: true),
     aW(day: 5, w: 31.61, m: false),
     aW(day: 6, w: 31.41, m: false),
     aW(day: 7, w: 31.20, m: true),
     aW(day: 8, w: 31.01, m: true),
     aW(day: 9, w: 30.83, m: true)].publisher
   
      array
     .reduce(0) {$1.m ? $0 : $0 + 1}
     .sink(receiveValue: { print($0) }) // 3
     .store(in: &subscriptions)
```

Answer (score -1):

Map the items in an array of tuples with the property you want to count as key:

```
let mappedItems = array.map { ($0.m, 1) }
```

Then use this `Dictionary` initializer to add the values if it finds duplicate keys.

```
let counts = Dictionary(mappedItems, uniquingKeysWith: +)
```

this prints:

> [true: 7, false: 3]

Comment: this would unnecessarily iterate the whole collection twice

Comment: You can also avoid repeating the same element `1` while using map. Imagine if you have a million elements.`Dictionary(zip(array.map(\.m), repeatElement(1, count: array.count)), uniquingKeysWith: +)`.  Btw I still don't like iterating the array twice.